# Webform 'Save draft' to send a mail with $sid

Tags: 6, webforms, forms

- I am having a webform and I display the 'Save Draft' buttoan on the form.
- Once I click on the Save draft I need to save all the values in the DB (as it does on Submit event) and should send an e-mail with the submission id (%sid) to the user who works on the form.
- I don't want to do this using "Webform Rules" module, I want to do this using my Own custom module

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use webform rules for this.  However if you are wanting to do this in a custom module then I suggest you looks at [hook_webform_submission_insert](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/6) or [hook_webform_submission_update](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_update/6) depending on whether it's a new webform submission or not.

From there you can use modules such as [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to obtain the information on the submission status you require.  I haven't worked with 6 for a while now, so I may be wrong here, but I think it's `is_draft` you need to use. (I haven't got a D6 site to test on).  With this information you can write a function to send the mail using [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6)